# Member cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead

Tags: c#, static, xna

I have a game. It has a `Level` class for drawing the level, managing blocks, etc. I also have a `Tile` class for each individual tile (type, x, y), and a block class for the type of block.

I get the error:

`Member cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead`

In

```
Texture2D texture = tiles[x, y].blockType.Dirt_Block.texture;
```

Here is my Tile.cs

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Game.Tiles;

namespace Game
{
public struct Tile
{
    public BlockType blockType;
    public  int X;
    public  int Y;

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new tile for one position
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="blocktype">Type of block</param>
    /// <param name="x">X Axis position</param>
    /// <param name="y">Y Axis position</param>
    public Tile(BlockType blocktype,int x,int y)
    {
        blockType = blocktype;
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }
}
}
```

And block.cs...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Game.Tiles;


namespace Game.Tiles
{

/// <summary>
/// Controls the collision detection and response behavior of a tile.
/// </summary>
enum BlockCollision
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A passable tile is one which does not hinder player motion at all.
    /// </summary>
    Passable = 0,

    /// <summary>
    /// An impassable tile is one which does not allow the player to move through
    /// it at all. It is completely solid.
    /// </summary>
    Impassable = 1,

    /// <summary>
    /// A platform tile is one which behaves like a passable tile except when the
    /// player is above it. A player can jump up through a platform as well as move
    /// past it to the left and right, but can not fall down through the top of it.
    /// </summary>
    Platform = 2,
}
public enum BlockType
{
     Dirt_Block = new Block("Dirt Block",,BlockCollision.Impassable,250,0,0)
}
/// <summary>
/// Stores the appearance and collision behavior of a tile.
/// </summary>
public struct Block
{

    public static string Name;
    public static Texture2D Texture;
    public static BlockCollision Collision;
    public static int Width = 16;
    public static int Height = 16;
    public static int maxAmount;
    public static int Worth;
    public static int Strength;

    public static Vector2 Size = new Vector2(Width, Height);

    /// <summary>
    /// Contructs a new block
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="name">Name of the block</param>
    /// <param name="texture">Texture to use as image</param>
    /// <param name="collision">Collision type</param>
    /// <param name="maxamount">Maximum amount of these blocks you can have</param>
    /// <param name="worth">How much this block is worth</param>
    /// <param name="strength">How hard the block is (how much you will have to hit to mine it)</param>
    public Block(string name, Texture2D texture,BlockCollision collision, int       maxamount, int worth, int strength)
    {
        Name = name;
        Texture = texture;
        Collision = collision;
        Width = 16;
        Height = 16;
        maxAmount = maxamount;
        Worth = worth;
        Strength = strength;
    }
}
}
```

I'm not even sure if its an efficient way to make a `new tile(blockType,x,y)` for every block on the grid. Any help would be appreciated. Mainly; How can I get the value of `blockType.Dirt_Block.Texture`? But I get the error about something not being static or whatever.

http://pastebin.com/s50AB6kz

**EDIT:** Looking back at this I feel really stupid, but I will leave it here since obviously 10k views means it has helped someone

Comment: Your use of enum BlockType is... non traditional.  I would have a Block base class and derived types for the various kinds of blocks, and then you can interrogate their types directly if need be.

Comment: Obviously my way isnt gonna work.. where to next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is not legal, because an enum member can only have an integer value.

```
public enum BlockType
{
     Dirt_Block = new Block("Dirt Block",,BlockCollision.Impassable,250,0,0)
}
```

`Dirt_Block` is a static member of the `BlockType` type, so you can't access the `Dirt_Block` member on an instance of `BlockType`.

And I think you misunderstand what enums are; enum members can't have enums of their own.

Comment: Well I think My method is not going to work, So were should I go next. I was trying to do this because I implemented this: http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/84194/507476.aspx#507476 And I made it so If you click, it finds the correct texture and draws a block of it. but then theres anouther list called lines[x][y], and I have to update that too it seems... Wait I just relized this isnt gonna work. Were to now? I need a way to be able to define block types, and for each grid position, a way to see what texture used, x,y, etc

Comment: Make BlockType a class rather than an enum, and declare a Texture property in it

Comment: Ah why didnt I think of that!

Comment: So maybe something like this? `public class BlockType
{
     public BlockType Dirt_Block = new Block("Dirt Block",,BlockCollision.Impassable,250,0,0);`  How would i get the variables from the Blocktype?
     
}

Answer (score 4):

`static` variables are the same for ALL instances of that type. Take all of the `static`s off of Block and you should be fine.

Also make `BlockType` and `Block` `class`es instead of an `enum` and `struct`, respectively, since they are neither `enum`s nor `struct`s.